# Public Array Variable Not Setting PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am trying set a public variable with an array of the query results.  I don't know what im doing wrong but my variable is not setting.

```
public $rows;

public function Query($Sql){
    $Results = mysqli_query($this->_Connection, $Sql);
    if(!$Results){
       die("Query Failed: ". mysqli_error($this->_Connection));
    }
    while ($row = $Results->fetch_assoc()) {
           $Results_Array[] = $row;
    }       
    $this->rows = $Results_Array;
}
```

I know the sql is working because if i just return $Results it works.  Also if i "return $Results_Array" it works just fine. So using "return" works fine. It is only when i add the step of setting the public variable with the array using $this->rows = $Results_Array; i get the error.

I am using an intance to return the var like so $Db->rows and am getting a empty var.

Comment: You are using classes fr this right?

Comment: Yes this is inside a class.

Comment: Dump rows out in that function only and tell me its working or not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to have wasted everyone's time.  Thank you for the replys.  I found my issue and it was not related to the function itself it was related to how i was calling the var outside of the function/class.  I was calling the wrong class.